# Android animated-rotate drawable: Where is official documentation?

Tags: android, animation, rotation, android-drawable

Where is the official documentation for `animated-rotate` drawable?!!
I searched for `"animated-rotate" site:developer.android.com` and didn't find anything:

> No results found for **"animated-rotate" site:developer.android.com**.

[image]

Also in official site:

[image]

If so, why I could use below drawable in my app and running it successfully?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animated-rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_spinner_pb"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:fromDegrees="0.0"
        android:toDegrees="360.0" />
```

[image]

Comment: it is hidden [class](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/graphics/java/android/graphics/drawable/AnimatedRotateDrawable.java#39) so there is no documentation for it

Comment: @pskink; Thanks. If you post your comment as an answer, I will accept it. The link itself was useful.